# Why can't 'use' statement be in include file?

Tags: php

Why can't my `use` statement be placed inside an `include` file?

This works fine:

```
require_once("PHPMailer_Loader.php");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

SendEmailWindows("foo@bar.com", "smtp test", "test body");

function SendEmailWindows($emailTo, $subject, $body){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    [... all the rest of the function code]
}
```

Yet when I try to move those 2 `use` statements into my **PHPMailer_Loader.php** script (placed at the very bottom of the file), it breaks with this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in [...]\EmailTester.php on line 12
```

Just for tidyness and compactness I'd like to move everything into the `include` except for the function and the calling line.

Comment: It maybe because you have the wrong path file to phpmailer

Comment: No, the path is correct. If it weren't, then my working example (shown above) wouldn't work either.

Comment: `PHPMailer_Loader.php` was made custom by me, it has settings and other includes that I need. I don't need to use `PHPMailerAutoload.php`, and my working examples works fine without that. Composer is one more extra install and step, I don't need it.

Comment: `use` statement is per file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PHP manual is saying this:

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. [...] **Importing rules are per file basis**, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

The `"Importing rules are per file basis"` part being the important one here.

You *can* `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` in your `include` file, but that only means that `PHPMailer` *(without having to specify the full class name)* will be available inside your `include` file and ***not in the parent file*** *(the one which includes your `include` file)*.

#### tl;dr

You need to specify your `use ...;` statements in **every** file you want that specific `use` to apply.

Comment: You're welcome. And it's not _that_ bad. ;) If you really want to get rid of those `use` statements, just don't "use" them and refer to those classes in the code by their full name. It will work either way.